# nested for loop in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to implement the following nested for loop-

```
for(int i=2000;i<=2013;i++)
  for (int j=i+1;j<=2014;j++)
   {
     }
```

I tried the following

```
for i in {2000..2013}
 do
  for j in {$((i+1))..2014}
   do
   done
 done
```

but it's not working. Anybody can help. please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash has syntax for C-like loops.

```
for ((i=2000;i<=2013;i++)); do
  for ((j=i+1;j<=2014;j++)); do
    : stuff
  done
done
```

This is not portable to other shells (notably `sh` / `dash`).